# Step of a proof in $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, modules

> Consider $R$ a commutative ring with unity. Then all the $R$-modules are free iff $R$ is a field. Let $M$ be an $R$-module.

$\Leftarrow$ is clear as $M$ is an $R$-vector space that has a basis. For the converse, consider $I$ a maximal ideal of $R$. I want to prove that $I$ is 0. Firstly I consider  $\dfrac{R}{I}$ that is a $R$ module, so it is free. $\dfrac{R}{I}$ does not have any proper ideal, apart from $0$, as its ideal would contain $I$, which is a maximal ideal. Then $R/I\cong R^{(\Lambda)}$. Now, $\# \Lambda$ cannot be 0 (if it was 0 then $\dfrac{R}{I}$ would be 0 modules, that is false by hypothesis). $\# \Lambda$ can be 1, but cannot be greater than 1, and I cannot understand why. During lessons, I wrote, "Because of if $\# \Lambda >1$ then there are non-trivial submodules". I cannot understand this last implication i.e why if $\#\Lambda>1$ then $\dfrac{R}{I}$ has non-trivial ideal.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to show the implication “If $R$ is not a field, then there is a non-free $R$-module”?

Comment: Let $J$ be an $R$-submodule of $R/I$. It's pulback under $R\rightarrow R/I$ defines a submodule of $R$ containing $I$.

Comment: @eduard this is clear to me. But my point is: if $R/I \cong R^2 $ (for instance, let's assume $\#\Lambda = 2$) why $R/I$ should have submodules? Maybe my question is not clear enough

Comment: @Joppy this is what I firstly try: If $R$ is not a field then exists $x\neq 0$ s.t $x$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. But I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Let $J$ as above. Then its pullback $I'$ is an ideal of $R$ containg $I$, since the submodules of $R$ are the ideals of $R$. That is, $I'$ is either $R$ or $I$. If $I'=R$ then $J=R/I$. If $I' = I$ then...

Comment: Suppose that $R$ has a nonzero ideal $I$. Let $x$ be a nonzero element of $I$. Then $R/I$ has some nonzero element $m$, but $xm = 0 \in R/I$. Hence $R$ has a non-free module $R/I$.

Comment: @Joppy and $R/I$ is not free because it has torsion, right? And why a free module should not have torsion?. For instance, it seems to me that $\mathbb{Z}/n{Z}^{\Lambda}$ with $\#\Lambda <\infty$ could have torsion. Am I wrong?

Comment: A free module cannot have torsion, since if $m$ is a torsion element in a free module, it can be expressed as a linear combination of basis vectors. Applying an element $x$ that kills $m$ would cause a linear dependence amongst these basis vectors, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $R/I$ is a so called simple module when $I$ is a maximal ideal; it has no proper submodules.  But if $\#\Lambda>0$, then $R^{(\Lambda)}$ must have a proper submodule, namely in the form of direct summand copies of $R$. Thus $R/I$ has proper submodules, which cannot be.

To illustrate: If $\#\Lambda=2$.  Then $R^{(\Lambda)} \cong R^2=R \oplus R$. Let $N=\{(a,0) \mid a \in R\} \subseteq R \oplus R$. Then $N$ is a proper submodule of $R^2$ that is a direct summand of $R \oplus R$, and is isomorphic to $R$. The point is, anytime you have a direct sum, the components of the direct sum sit inside as submodules.

Comment: For instance: Is it true that $I^{(\Lambda)}$ is and $R^{(\Lambda)}$ ideal and is proper because $I$ is maximal?

Comment: @ele You do not want to try and think of $R^{(\Lambda)}$ as a ring; indeed if $\#\Lambda$ is not finite, then $R^{(\Lambda)}$ does not inherit a ring structure from $R$ (it doesn't have identity).

Comment: @ metalspringpro sorry you are definitely right. So $N$ ad defined above is a proper _submodule_ of $R\oplus R$ which is isomorphic to $R/I$ as it's free. So is $N$ at least _isomorphic_ a proper ideal in $R$? In this way, I have done it. Is that correct?

Comment: @ele Yes, more generally any component of $R^{\#\Lambda}$ is a submodule of $R^{\#\Lambda}$.  If,$\#\Lambda \ne 1$, these are all proper submodules.  Since $R/I \cong R^{\#\Lambda}$, these correspond to submodules in $R/I$, otherwise known as ideals of $R/I$. As $I$ is maximal these cannot exist, so $\#\Lambda=1$.